# Xamarin target framework is not update

Tags: xamarin.android, android-sdk-manager, target-framework

I recently installed android sdk v10 (API 29) in order to set the target framework in my application to v10. But I still can't find it in my application property.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJCR.png)

I tried to reload the project but it did not work.
Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your visual studio version ? Is your Xamarin installation up to date? I suspect that your version of Xamarin.Android is 7.x which means that you won't be able to target Android 8.0 or above even if they are installed through the SDK manager.

You can check the version from **Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio**